# CentOS6.9 にMySQL8をインストールする際に発生したエラーの対処方法について

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

**概要：**
linuxサーバ(CentOS 6.9)にMySQL8をインストールする際に発生したエラーの対処方法について質問させてください。

MySQL8をyumでインストールしようとすると「インストールされたパッケージを更新しません。」というエラーが出て先に進めません。
解消方法を知っている方がいましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。

**OSのバージョン：**
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

**詳細(発生手順)**
(1) MySQL8の公式ページに移動する
2.5.1 Installing MySQL on Linux Using the MySQL Yum Repository
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

(2) rpmファイルのダウンロード
CentOS6.9のため以下のパッケージをダウンロードする。
「Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 / Oracle Linux 6 (Architecture Independent), RPM Package」
mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm

(3) 以下のyumコマンドを実行し、(2)でダウンロードしたものに対してlocalinstallを試みる

```
# yum localinstall mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm
```

(4) (3)の結果、以下のようなエラーが出てMySQL8のインストールができない状態です。

```
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, security ローカルパッケージ処理の設定をしています
mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm を調べています:
mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch
mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm: インストールされたパッケージを更新しません。
何もしません
```

念の為、`yum repolist` の実行内容も記載します。

```
# yum repolist

読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, security Loading mirror speeds from cached
hostfile  * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp  * epel: ftp.iij.ad.jp  * extras:
ftp.iij.ad.jp  * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp

リポジトリー ID                リポジトリー名                                       状態
base                           CentOS-6 - Base                                     6,713
epel                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64     12,584
extras                         CentOS-6 - Extras                                      47
mysql-connectors-community     MySQL Connectors Community                             28
mysql-tools-community          MySQL Tools Community                                  12
mysql80-community              MySQL 8.0 Community Server                             33
updates                        CentOS-6 - Updates                                    812
repolist: 20,229
```

なにかわかる方がいましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。

2020/01/06 17:30追記

アドバイス後、
`yum update` を実行したところ、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.73-8.el6_8 will be 不要
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) のパッケージ: 2:postfix-2.6.6-8.el6.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) のパッケージ: 2:postfix-2.6.6-8.el6.x86_64
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。 エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: 2:postfix-2.6.6-8.el6.x86_64
(@anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9)
             要求: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
            削除: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9)
                libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
            次のものにより不要にされた: : mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
                見つかりません エラー: パッケージ: 2:postfix-2.6.6-8.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9)
             要求: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
            削除: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9)
                libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
            次のものにより不要にされた: : mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
                見つかりません エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.5)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
             要求: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)  問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができません  これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

エラー内容から、CentOS8用のmysqlがどこかにインストールされてしまっているかもしれません。

Comment: 「インストールされたパッケージを更新しません。」と表示されていますので、mysql80-community-release-el6-3 パッケージが既にインストールされているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確認させて頂きます。

Comment: コマンドの結果を貼り付ける際は、なるべく `{}` を使うようにしてもらうと見やすく表示されます。 ("引用" はプレーンなテキスト向けの装飾になります)

Comment: 修正していただきありがとうございます。
まだ、不慣れなところがありますが、
今後は、コマンドの結果は{}を使うようにします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum repolist` の一覧に表示されているということは、既にインストール済みでかつリポジトリも有効になった状態のはずなので、`yum update` の後に `yum search mysql` でパッケージがヒットするかを確認してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
早速、yum updateを実行したところ、新たなエラー(このあと投稿内容に記載します)。エラー内容のところで
「mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64」を読もうとしていることから、cent os 8用のmysqlを読み込もうとしているように思えます。

Comment: `yum update` だとパッケージのアップデートでしたね、失礼しました。`yum check-update` の方が良かったかもしれません。 / インストールされているかは `yum list mysql` で確認できるはずです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
yum list mysqlの実行結果を確認したところ、
「mysql.x86_64 」がインストールされているようでした。


{$yum list mysql
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp-srv2.kddilabs.jp
 * epel: nrt.edge.kernel.org
 * extras: ftp-srv2.kddilabs.jp
 * updates: ftp-srv2.kddilabs.jp
利用可能なパッケージ
mysql.x86_64                                                                5.1.73-8.el6_8                                                                 base
}

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
アドバイスのおかげで、無事にmysql8のインストールができました！

原因は、(手順を書く前のところで)CentOS 8用のmysql「mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm」をダウンロードしてしまい、
それをインストールしていたことが問題でした。本来は、CentOS 6用のmysqlをダウンロードのが正解でした。
よって、CentOS 8用のmysqlを削除し、CentOS 6用のmysqlを入れ直したら、正しく動作するようになりました。

Answer (score 2):

**自己解決**

アドバイスのおかげで、無事にmysql8のインストールができました！

原因は、(発生手順を書く前のところで)CentOS8用のmysql「mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm」をダウンロードし、インストールしていたことが問題でした。
ダウンロード、インストールを実施したコマンド。

```
yum localinstall -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm
```

それが原因で、以下のようなエラーが出ていたようです。
ライブラリー「libcrypto.so.1.1」は、CentOS8用で、CentOS6用ではない。

```
要求: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
```

その結果、サーバーはCentOS６なのにCentOS8用のmysqlがインストールされてしまいました。

対処方法としては、CentOS 8用のmysqlをyumのリポジトリからも削除し、CentOS 6用のmysqlをインストールし直したら、正しく動作するようになりました。