# CentOS7 への MySQL インストール時にエラー Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1 (OPENSSL_1_1_1)

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

MySQLがインストールできません。なぜでしょうか？

```
sudo yum localinstall -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-2.noarch.rpm
```

でrpmパッケージをインストールした後、`yum clean all`して以下を実行しましたがエラーが出てしまいます。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql80-community-release-el7-2.noarch

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.riken.jp
 * epel: nrt.edge.kernel.org
 * extras: ftp.riken.jp
 * remi-safe: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
mysql-connectors-community                                                                       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Not using downloaded mysql-connectors-community/repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
  Current   : Fri Jan 10 15:51:55 2020
  Downloaded: Fri Jan 10 15:51:49 2020
mysql-tools-community                                                                            | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Not using downloaded mysql-tools-community/repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
  Current   : Fri Jan 10 18:32:38 2020
  Downloaded: Fri Jan 10 18:32:21 2020
mysql80-community                                                                                | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Not using downloaded mysql80-community/repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
  Current   : Thu Jan  9 11:17:17 2020
  Downloaded: Thu Jan  9 11:16:12 2020
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 8.0.19-1.el8 for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 8.0.11 for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 8.0.11 for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.19-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libncurses.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

whatprovodesもできません。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ yum whatprovides libcrypto
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: ty1.mirror.newmediaexpress.com
 * epel: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * extras: ty1.mirror.newmediaexpress.com
 * remi-safe: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ty1.mirror.newmediaexpress.com
google-chrome                                                                                                       3/3
google-chrome-unstable                                                                                              3/3
ius                                                                                                             867/867
base/7/x86_64/filelists_db                                                                       | 7.3 MB  00:00:01
epel/x86_64/filelists_db                                                                         |  12 MB  00:00:04
extras/7/x86_64/filelists_db                                                                     | 210 kB  00:00:00
google-chrome/filelists                                                                          | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
google-chrome-unstable/filelists                                                                 | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
ius/x86_64/filelists                                                                             | 978 kB  00:00:00
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/x86_64/repodata/a2946eb6db702dd121080817aa8cf41a45f33ae9-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.



 One of the configured repositories failed (MySQL Connectors Community),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=mysql-connectors-community ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable mysql-connectors-community
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=mysql-connectors-community

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=mysql-connectors-community.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/a2946eb6db702dd121080817aa8cf41a45f33ae9-filelists.sqlite.bz2 from mysql-connectors-community: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/x86_64/repodata/a2946eb6db702dd121080817aa8cf41a45f33ae9-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

MariaDBは消しました。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ yum list installed | grep mariadb
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
```

CentOS7です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 重複候補: [CentOS6.9 にMySQL8をインストールする際に発生したエラーの対処方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61997)

Comment: 依存性の確認後、`mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el8.x86_64` のように末尾が **el8** のパッケージをインストールしようとしているので、そもそも初めの [Yum リポジトリファイル](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/) でインストールしたファイルが間違っている可能性があります。

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep mysql` を実行して mysql80-community-release の末尾を確認してみてください。CentOS7 なら本来 `mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch` のように **el7** が含まれるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql80-community-release-el7-2.noarch　　今はel7になってますが、最初el8を入れてしまい、後ほどrpm -e mysql80-community-releaseして入れ直しました。

Comment: 行ったことを、覚えている範囲で良いので、質問文に記載したほうが良いかと思います。/自分の環境で試して再現しましたが、 `sudo yum clean all` で解消しました。(念の為ですが、 `sudo` を付与して実行されましたか？)

Comment: ありがとうございます。sudoもキャッシュクリアもしてましたが、質問欄に挙げたような結果になりました。今はビルドの途中でまたエラーが出てしまったので、vagrant destroyしてしまったので再度試せませんが、もう一度yum localinstallで試してみます。

Comment: 新しい環境でyum localinstallしたところあっけなくインストールできました。元の環境が結構前に作成したものだったのでその影響かと思います。お騒がせしました。

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSLは2019/12/31をもって1.1.1未満のサポートを終了しています。
MySQLを含む各ソフトウェアが1.1.1にリンクするのも当然ではあります。
一方、パッケージマネージャーはそれぞれ独自の管理を行なっており、CentOS7ではOpenSSL 1.1.1は提供しない方針なのでしょう。

そのため、

- パッケージマネージャーに依存せず全て自前でビルドする
- パッケージマネージャーの提供するパッケージを使用する

のどちらかを選択する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 cubickさんにいただいた回答を試してからこちらの方法も試してみたいと思います。

Comment: ひとつ疑問があるのですが、centosにおいてパッケージマネージャーとはyumの事ではないんでしょうか？yum install mysql-community-serverすることは「パッケージマネージャーの提供するパッケージを使用する」ということに当たらないんでしょうか？

Comment: 自分でビルドするか、yum install するかという意味ですよね多分。ありがとうございました。